# Настройка ProFTPD (доступ к файлам через FTP)

Tags: ftp

Есть два пользователя ftp: админский (с полным доступом к файлам сайта) и пользовательский. Каким образом на стороне сервера пользовательскому аккаунту ftp можно запретить доступ к некоторым файлам/папкам? Например ко всем исполняемым скриптам (php и прочее), запретить загружать такие же файлы, запретить доступ/изменение/загрузку .htaccess ?
Пользователь должен иметь возможность загружать файлы, тексты, html-странички, скрипты, изображения, но не более того.
На сервере используется Plesk Panel, в ней настроек доступа подобного рода нет, потому нужно самому:)

**Дополнение:**
Стал разбираться с настройками .ftpaccess и наткнулся на такой момент:

```
<Directory *>
HideFiles ^\.(ftpaccess|htaccess)$
PathDenyFilter "(\\.ftpaccess|\\.htaccess)$"
</Directory>
```

Это позволяет скрыть некоторые файлы из области видимости (HideFiles), а так же запретить редактировать эти файлы (PathDenyFilter).
Чтобы запретить просмотр файлов для конкретного пользователя, можно воспользоваться конструкцией:

```
HideFiles ^\.(ftpaccess|htaccess)$ user myuser
```

при подключении через ftp пользователь "myuser" не увидит указанные файлы, но он всё ещё может их изменять. Эту проблему я попытался решить очевидным для меня способом:

```
PathDenyFilter "(\\.ftpaccess|\\.htaccess)$" user myuser
```

но он таки не сработал.
Потому вопрос остаётся актуальным: Как запретить пользователю редактировать/загружать некоторые файлы через ftp?

Answer (score 1):

[manual](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/ru-RU/online/plesk-customer-guide/index.htm?fileName=70738.htm), ну и как варинт просто из ОС chmod))

Comment: Спасибо:) Но это совсем не то, что мне нужно:)